RST Sphinx custom extension for xml
I am trying to understand how to create a custom Sphinx extension which can be executed only when creating XML. I would like to put a custom RST directive
.. mycustom:: 

and output a consequent XML tag
<mycustom></mycustom>

I am calling the nodes.raw() function but it adds an envelope <raw></raw> tag to my custom tag which I cannot remove. I am starting from the example HelloWorld directive help which can be found on the site, adding some minor modifications to it.
Thanks in advance to whom will help me better understanding.

You may have found a bug in the Docutils XML writer.
nodes.raw is the class implementing the <raw> document tree element:

Passed untouched to the Writer. The interpretation is up to the Writer.

Most writers (HTML, LaTeX, …) ignore <raw> elements in a "foreign" format and write the content of <raw> elements matching their format directly into the output.
The "XML" writer is special, as it also stores "foreign" <raw> elements (with escaping special characters in the content).
Handling of <raw format="xml"> is a bit of a mix: XML-markup in the content is not escaped but the wrapper is kept.
You may consider getting rid of the <raw> </raw> wrapper in post-processing, filing a bug report at https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/bugs/, or using a custom XML writer.
